# wordpress site shows Skip to content

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssl, amazon-ec2

I am using LAMP stack in AWS Ubuntu 16 EC2 instance. http and https working fine normal site at /var/www/html. I installed wordpress and configure apache2.conf to refer wordpress site. Https wasn't working. Hence I did the following:

Change1: Wordpress wp-admin -> Settings -> General -> site url and home changed to https://wpdev.xxxxx.com (Result: Skip to content when I access page)
Change2: Added define('FS_METHOD','direct') and define('WP_HOME'.. and define('WP_SITEURL'...) to point to https://ryde...com. (Result: Same error)

Change3: Added. htaccess file under wordpress site with the below content. 
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://wpdev.xxxxx.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>`

(Result: Same error)

May I know what correct settings I should do to make wordpress work with https://wpdev.xxxxx.com?

My current site url: https://rydewpdev.rydesharing.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because your setup is loading CSS/JS content over `http`. Install the awesome [WordPress HTTPS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/#installation) plugin, and configure it to force https for all static content.

Comment: Great. Working fine. Thanks a lot. I struggled for 2 days and did lot of search. Finally this solution made me success.